# group of molecules

Tags: chemfig

I want to reproduce this figure, [image]

i used `chemfig` package, need help to get many arrows from one molecules.
Thank you

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\chapterstyle{tandh}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setarrowdefault{315,1.5,thick}
\schemestart 
\chemname{\fbox{{\tiny\chemfig{O=[:-30]
*6(-(-(-[::275])(-[::95])-)=N-N=(-S(-[::-30]))-N(-{NH_2})-)}}}}{Metribuzin}
\arrow 
\small\chemfig{O=[:-30]*6(-(-C(-[::275])(-[::95])-)=N-N=(-S(-[::-30]{CH_3}))-N(-{NH_2})-)}
\schemestop\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: What seems to be your question? When I process your sample code I get two compounds and an arrow between them. What seems to be the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to have many arrows coming out from the main molecule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to study the syntax of the `\arrow`:

- `\arrow[<angle>]`: give an angle for the arrow (default `0`)
- `\arrow(<node name>--)`: give a name to the compound where the arrow starts
- `\arrow(--<node name>)`: give a name to the compound where the arrow ends
- `\arrow(<node name>--<node name>)`: give a name to the compound where the arrow starts and to the one where the arrow ends
- `\arrow(@<node name>--)`: let the arrow start at a compound of the given name
- `\arrow(--@<node name>)`: let the arrow end at a compound of the given name
- `\arrow(@<node name>--@<node name>)`: connect two given compounds; **the `@<node name>` syntax allows to add several arrows from or to a compound, so it is the key to your question**.
- `\arrow(<node name>--)[<angle>]`: possible combination of the optional arguments
- `\arrow(<node name>[<tikz style>]--)`: add `<tikz style>` to the compound `<node name>`. `<node name>` is optional here: `\arrow([<tikz style>]--)`
- Compounds actually have names even if you don't assign any: they're called `c1`, `c2`, … If you want to see which compound has which name then add `\schemedebug{true}` before `\schemestart`.

There are many more details which are all explained in part IV of the chemfig manual. It is also worth to study part VI (a gallery containing lot's of examples).

Here is one possibility for the given scheme (to keep the code of the scheme short I defined submols for every compound). I added a few comments which hopefully explain why the code is there and what it does.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
% \usepackage{showframe} % shows page dimensions

\definesubmol{Metribuzin}{O=[:30]*6(-N(-NH_2)-(-S-[::60])=N-N=(-(-[::-60])(-[::60])-)-)}
\definesubmol{I1}{O=[:30]*6(-N(-NH_2)-(-S(=[::-60]O)-[::60])=N-N=(-(-[::-60])(-[::60])-)-)}
\definesubmol{DK}{O=[:30]*6(-N(-NH_2)-(=O)=N-N=(-(-[::-60])(-[::60])-)-)}
\definesubmol{DADK}{O=[:30]*6(-N(-H)-(=O)=N-N=(-(-[::-60])(-[::60])-)-)}
\definesubmol{DA}{O=[:30]*6(-N(-H)-(-S-[::60])=N-N=(-(-[::-60])(-[::60])-)-)}
\definesubmol{I2}{O=[:30]*6(-N(-H)-(-S(=[::-60]O)-[::60])=N-N=(-(-[::-60])(-[::60])-)-)}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  % adjustments so the scheme fits within \textwidth:
  \small
  \setatomsep{1.5em}
  % a TikZ style for drawing a box around a compound:
  \tikzset{boxcompound/.style={draw,inner sep=2pt}}
  \schemestart
    \chemname
      {\chemfig{!{Metribuzin}}}
      {Metribuzin}
    \arrow(Metribuzin[boxcompound]--)[-20] % give the starting compound the name `Metribuzin' and draw a box around it
    \chemname{\chemfig{!{I1}}}{}
    \arrow(--DK[boxcompound])[-90] % give the arriving compound the name `DK' and draw a box around it
    \chemname{\chemfig{!{DK}}}{DK}
    \arrow(--DADK[boxcompound])[180] % give the arriving compound the name `DADK' and draw a box around it
    \chemname{\chemfig{!{DADK}}}{DADK}
    \arrow[-90]
    Mineralisation
    \arrow(@Metribuzin--DA[boxcompound])[-160] % start from `Metribuzin', give the arriving compound the name `DA' and draw a box around it
    \chemname{\chemfig{!{DA}}}{DA}
    \arrow[-90]
    \chemname{\chemfig{!{I2}}}{}
    \arrow(--@DADK) % draw an arrow to `DADK'
    \arrow(@Metribuzin--@DK) % connect `Metribuzin' with `DK'
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```