# Drawing organic reaction?

Tags: chemfig

I have been trying to draw this but i couldn't accomplish it :(
[image]

I have tried but failed .

I tried like this

```
\chemfig{**(-=-=-=)} \+ \chemfig(3O_3) \arrow(->) No idea here \arrow{->[\chemfig{3H_2O}][\chemfig{Zn.$Delta$}) ]} chemfig{3 CHO-CHO}
```

but it doens't appear i as wish . There is always problem with centering reaction and many problem :(

Comment: Hello, and welcome to TeX.SE. When posting questions it helpful to post a minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. That way all of us can see what packages you are working with and environments that you are using!

Comment: Also a better drawing of the Benzene Triozonide molecule will help!

Comment: @PaulStiverson Sorry for Benzene trioznide . I just want to know the structure only from \chemfig :)  and by the way i have lot of discussion  can i chat with you ?

Comment: @aftershock Don't edit the question with new content. If it's a new question, ask a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a possible solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6(=-=-=-)}\arrow{0}[,0]\+ 3\,\chemfig{O_3}
\arrow
\chemname{\chemfig{O*5(-\chembelow{C}{H}(-[::-18]\chembelow{C}{H}*5([:10]-O-O-[,,,1]CH(-[::-18,,1]CH*5([:120]-[,,1]O-O-\chemabove{C}{H}?-O-[,,,1]))-O-))-[,,1]O-\chemabove{C}{H}?-O-)}}{Benzenetriozonide}
\arrow(--.mid west){->[3\,\chemfig{H_2O}][Zn, $\Delta$]}[,1.2] 3\,\chemname{\chemfig{CHO-[2]CHO}}{Glyoxal\\(Ethanedial)} \+ 3\,\chemfig{H_2O_2}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

EDIT I add all the CH. The `\chemabove{C}{H}` command put the H above (or below if you use `\chembelow`) the C atom.
[image: reaction]

Comment: structure of benzene ozonide is not correct

Comment: We don't know the structure of benzine ozonide. This is why we need a better drawing of it!!!

Comment: @aftershock I'm sorry it's not correct, but i have used this [picture](https://www.google.it/search?q=benzene+triozonide&client=ubuntu&hs=CI6&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&imgil=C1RWu29nWedqbM%253A%253B3wVyDVVVMajI9M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fchem-guide.blogspot.com%25252F2010%25252F04%25252Fchemical-properties-of-benzene.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=C1RWu29nWedqbM%253A%252C3wVyDVVVMajI9M%252C_&usg=__ILktWSV3K8KOkvtg74Hbb8kiWAw%3D). Can you show us a picture of benzene triozonide? Your picture is wrong, there aren't enough oxygen and carbons

Comment: @skevin93 Ok i have edited and provided good image now :)

Comment: Your new image it's the same i used to build my example. Can you explain me why my example it's wrong?

Comment: @skevin93 sorry your answer is not wrong but i want to show the carbon atoms also :) please do it and it will be ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- The first shape can be created by specifying the number of sides.
- I used `\chemrel` for the arrows but the editor was complaining that it was deprecated. Not sure about this since the manual still has the command. Besides it works.
- I scaled the second graph a bit, it was too big, but feel free to modify it as you want.
- On the second graph, the screenshot below shows some artifacts. Those are due to the PDF viewer. Zooming in fixes the issue.
- Also, please include a full MWE next time.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\emptydisk}{
\chemskipalign\tikz\draw(0,0)circle(3pt);
}
\newcommand{\nodisk}{
\chemskipalign\tikz\path(0,0)circle(3pt);
}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} \chemfig{x30_3} 
\chemrel{->}
\chemname{
\scalebox{.5}{
\chemfig{%
    \emptydisk
        (-[:90,2]\emptydisk(-[:0]))
    (-[:0]
        (-[:-45]
            (-[:45,.5]\emptydisk
                (-[:45,.5]
                    (-[:90,2]
                        (-[:135]\nodisk))))
                        (-[:-45]\emptydisk
                            (-[:45]\emptydisk
                                (-[:135]))))
        (-[:90]\emptydisk
            (-[:90]
                (-[:45]\emptydisk
                    (-[:45]\emptydisk)))))      
}}}{Benzene\\Triozonide}
\chemrel[$3H_2O$][Zn.$\Delta$]{->} 3 \chemname{\chemfig{(-[::+90,.7]CHO)(-[::-90,.5]CHO)}}{Glyoxal\\(Ethanedial)}
\schemestop 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advertise `\chemrel`. Using it writes the following in the log file: `Package chemfig Warning: the macro \chemrel is deprecated. Please, build schemes with \schemestart and inside, use \arrow.`

Comment: @clemens I see, what is the syntax for `\arrow` to have nodes like `\chemrel`?

Comment: Also, is it possible to set the position of `\arrow`, like baseline, etc?

Comment: `\arrow` is *very* flexible, lot's of things are possible, see for example here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251096/5049 Another example is an answer I gave here http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5734#5738 Also the `chemfig` manual has a gallery including various examples, it explains anchoring, placing labels, …